# Why is my favicon not working in my next js app?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, favicon, vercel

For some reason my favicon is not working.

I have the favicon saved as favicon.ico in the /public directory and am referencing it in the `<Head>` of my pages (located in the /pages directory) but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

-

Here is my code for my index.js:

```
  <Head>
      <title>Create Next App</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

```
dir/pages/index.js
dir/public/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Are you trying to see it locally or through a hosted online service?

Comment: I'm trying to see it locally. But it doesn't work when I deploy it to Vercel's Now either

Comment: I would try to replace your relative path to the icon to the actual path (locally) and see if it works locally. Also add the type attribute ```type="image/x-icon"```.

Comment: Nope, that's not working. Could it be because I am repeating the <Head> component with the <link> tag on each page (index.js, whats-on.js etc.) instead of just creating a  single <Head> component that contains the <link> ?

Comment: What's the exact problem, that the icon is unreachable through the web server or that the browser is not fetching it and using it in the expected locations?

Comment: Are they all located in the same directory relative to the path to the favicon? Can you try just having one page with the reference to the favicon and seeing if that works?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is unreachable or if the browser is fetching it. How do I find that out?

Next js is meant to automatically direct image urls to the /public directory. I'm actually using an official next.js template which already referenced its own favicon.ico (which I replaced with mine) but even before I did anything to the app the favicon wasn't working.

I've tried the path '../public/favicon.ico' despite Next being meant to automatically direct it but that's not working either.

Comment: To determine if the favicon is reachable you can try to load it in your browser. Type the URL in the location bar (that bar on top where you type google queries). To determine if the browser is recognising it as favicon you can check whether it shows up in the page tab.

Comment: Yes, the favicon is reachable

Comment: It's reachable at /favicon.ico as expected (not /public/favicon.ico)

Answer (score 58):

Put the favicons in an `/image` directory inside the `/public` directory and put the code below in your `_app.js`

```
<Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png"/>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png"/>
</Head>
```

Comment: I confirm this.

Comment: This worked for me I was migrating from the next js version 8 to 11 and this works.

Comment: Why is this necessary? It fixed my issue however I've noticed the Next.js boilerplate project does not do this and it seems to work there ...

Comment: It works in _document.js too.

Comment: My favicon was working perfectly on every other page except the 404 page. This worked for me and I don't know why? @sambecker have you discovered why this configuration works this way? Quite weird.

Comment: I’m not sure @Eke but in case it helps, one of the mistakes I made  was using a convenience component within `<Head />`. Apparently all links must be direct descendants of `<Head />`.

Comment: I just added it to a /public/image folder without adding any code to <Head> and it worked for me on next 12.2.3

Comment: They asked why it works this way, although the react documentation does not say about it. I found an article about favicon. Explain their logic and browser support and why so. --> https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/

Comment: Mine worked by changing the favicon.png location to inside image/ and href location. I couldn't find the reason behind why the location should be public/image/ ...

Answer (score 18):

It is possible that the `.ico` image was incorrectly created - perhaps converted online from a `.png`. This will cause the image to be viewable in the browser and elsewhere but unable to be used as a *favicon*.

In order to trouble shoot, try using a `.png` instead of `.ico` and see if the issue persists. If this solves your problem, consider using a converter targeted specifically for *favicons*, i.e. https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/

---

In my case, the file was in the correct place (`/public/favicon.ico`), was being referenced properly (`href="/favicon.ico"`), and was served when visiting `http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico`, yet it did not display in the browser tab until I reconverted it.

Answer (score 14):

I was facing exactly the same issue as you did.
It seems it is necessary to put the image file in /public/images/

It turns to work properly once I have done this.

Comment: saved my day. Such a confusing setup with working with nextjs, and lack of documentation. It's like find a needle  in haystack

Answer (score 9):

Only helpful if you are running into issues while using next **basePath**:

I was running into an issue where my favicon was not showing up. In my case it was because I was using `basePath: '/some-base-path'` in my next config. When you add a `basePath` it changes the path to the static assets.

Example: A basePath of `/test` with an image at `public/favicon.ico` can be referenced at `/test/public/favicon.ico`

Debugging note: I also had to clear my cache to see the changes (or try incognito).

Answer (score 4):

For me, I replaced the default `favicon.ico` file with a `favicon.png`. But it seems that for `jpg`, `png` extensions, the file needs to be named `icon.png`. Source:https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons

Answer (score 3):

In my case, **I had `public/` in the `src/`** directory.

I changed it to:

```
.
├── next.config.js
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── img
└── src
    ├── pages
    └── styles
```

(moved `public/` to the root `.`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For Next.js 11 (11.1.4) this solution worked both in dev and production (AWS Amplify).

Answer (score 3):

App router:

Place favicon.ico in public/img folder, then add this to layout.js

```
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
  </head>
```

Answer (score 2):

while building your app for production, just cut favicon.ico from root and paste into public folder.

Answer (score 1):

Working for Next v14.0.4

**Prenotes:**

1. I'm using /src folder
2. I'm using an SVG as favicon
3. I copied my file under /public/images for my project organization

**Instructions**

1. Delete your favicon.ico inside /src/app
2. Add your favicon.svg image inside /public/images
3. Modify your layout.tsx to include the icons metadata
4. Make sure you add **url** & **href** to the icon definition

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  // any other property you might have here.
  icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        url: "/images/icon_name.svg", // /public path
        href: "/images/icon_name.svg", // /public path
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone facing the same issue in Nextjs latest version (v14), move your icon to app directory and just rename the `favicon.ico` to `icon.ico`

Answer (score 0):

remove `/` from: `/favicon.ico` and your image should load if the format `ico` works. If it do not work convert the `.ico` image to `.png` or `.jpg`.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while I was creating my favicon, and it turns out that i've put the wrong image format in `type`! For example, I did this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico">
```

but it turns out I had to change `image/png` to `image/x-icon` because the formats didn't match.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue on @joematune answer, if you converted your .ico from .png or something like that, it will probably not work out of a random website. The readme.md file in the starter kit shares a link that converts it successfully. As a bouns, it also give you a bunch of variations (16x16, 32x32, apple-touch, etc.). Just replacing the old files with the new ones worked for me without modifying anything.

[this is the link](https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you think your configuration is correct but it's not still working, clear `.next` folder and run `yarn build` once again. Changes should apply this time.

Answer (score 0):

save favicon into /public, and use like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who uses `basePath` property in Next.js configuration file,
I have solved this issue to add my `basePath` value to `href` attribute of my `<link>` tag.

ex)

```
<link rel="icon" href="/[yourBasePath]/images/favicon.ico"
```

Answer (score 0):

working on next 14:

Put the favicon in the /app directory and like RogerKint said call it **icon.png or icon.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

✅ I've tried many ways but the only one that worked for me is the following:

- place your **icon.png** in **public folder** then add this link to the head of your layout.tsx.

```
<head>
        <link
          rel="icon"
          href="/icon.png"
        />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using next 14 and the new `/app` folder. The issue was that my favicons were under `/public/favicons` and as per the next documentation now are required in the root of the `/app` folder.

For reference
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons