Next.js favicon not showing in browser search results
I have a next.js site (v14.2.0), deployed on Vercel, where my favicon does not show in the browser search results however it does show in the browser tab.
Having read the following answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77997305/15824605 I have added an icon.ico file to the root of my projects app folder my app folder with a icon.ico file. As mentioned this does correctly set the icon in the browser tab although if I navigate to www.mysite/favicon.ico the icon here is the Vercel logo and this is what is displayed in the browser search results (even though I don't know of any reference to this logo in my code).
I have also tried renaming the file to favicon.ico as recommended by the next.js docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#favicon but when I do this the icon in the search results remains as the Vercel log and the icon in the browser tab is either also the Vercel logo or it's just not set.
Any ideas as to what might be causing this and what I could try to get the favicon displaying correctly?

browsers default to looking for /favicon.ico and often you deal with caching issues for a long time after changing metadata.  Put a favicon.ico in your /public
